# Trigger SNS at specified time

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a Lambda function that takes a list of tasks to be run at the time specified. This time can vary.

I am using SNS to trigger another Lambda function that in turn runs the tasks.
These tasks need to be run at specified time. Is it possible to publish a message to SNS using Lambda at the specified time? 
Or send the message to SNS, but SNS in turn triggers Lambda at the specified time?
Any option would do.

P.S. I know there is an option of using Cloud Watch events, but I do not want to use any more services.

Comment: Yes, use Amazon CloudWatch Events. (If you don't want to use any more services, then, no, it is not possible.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to trigger an AWS Lambda function at specific times.

This can be done by using **Amazon CloudWatch Events**, which can take a cron-like expression to run a Lambda function at desired time intervals or specific times. This functionality was **originally in the Lambda console**, but was moved to CloudWatch Events when more services added scheduling capabilities.

However, CloudWatch Events *cannot* trigger an Amazon SNS message. If you need SNS to trigger Lambda, then you'll need CloudWatch Events to trigger a Lambda function that sends a message to SNS (which then triggers Lambda functions). Obviously, it would be cleaner to avoid SNS altogether unless you specifically need to fan-out the message to multiple subscriptions/Lambda functions.